# Does AFNetworking support NTLM authentication?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, ntlm

Does AFNetworking support NTLM authentication?

I know ASIHTTPRequest can do it, i'm trying to migrate to AFNetworking, but i have to be sure it will be able to deal with it.

I really searched the internet for this, but i was unable to find this exact answer.

Thank you all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AFNetworking NTLM Authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483465/afnetworking-ntlm-authentication)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, AFNetworking does support NTLM authentication (or basically any authentication method) by providing a block-based response to authentication challenges in general.

Here's a code example (assuming `operation` is a `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, `AFJSONRequestOperation` etc.). Before starting the operation set the authentication challenge block like this:

```
[operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:
 ^( NSURLConnection* connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge* challenge )
{
   if( [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM )
   {
      if( [challenge previousFailureCount] > 0 )
      {
         // Avoid too many failed authentication attempts which could lock out the user
         [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
      }
      else
      {
         [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Authenticate in other ways than NTLM if desired or cancel the auth like this:
      [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
   }
}];
```

Start or enqueue the operation as usual and that should do the trick.

This is basically the method Wayne Hartman [describes in his blog](http://blog.waynehartman.com/articles/how-to-do-ntlm-authentication-in-ios.aspx) applied to AFNetworking.

Comment: Thank you sir, i didn't know that i could pass a block to deal with authentication!

I'm going to try it soon, but in my project i finished up making an small lib over ASIHTTPRequest that uses block syntax, that is what i was looking for =)

Comment: Started using your approach, works very well!
Thank you sir =)

Comment: Hmm, setAuthenticationChallengeBlock seems to be a property of a connection operation, not a request operation.