# NTLM authentication from ios Client

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, soap, webservice-client

I have a web-service in .net , that requires **NTLM** (Windows based in IIS Server) authentication before it can be access . How would I get **NTLM-authenticated from iOS Client.**

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but maybe this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483465/afnetworking-ntlm-authentication

Comment: I tried this code. But its not  being called didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a NSURLConnection and implement its delegate method

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge

In this delegate, check the challenge

```
[challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM]
```

if it is from the NTLM, then send the credential

```
NSURLCredential *credentail = [NSURLCredential
                                   credentialWithUser:<Your username>
                                   password: <Your password>
                                   persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

[[challenge sender] useCredential:credentail forAuthenticationChallenge:_challenge];
```

Comment: The `NSURLSession` counterpart is `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontaskdelegate/1411595-urlsession?language=objc