# How to implement NTLM authentication in Objective-C with NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm making cross-platform applications with Apache Cordova. Apache Cordova provides plugins to foresee native functionality. But the plugin to download and upload files doesn't support NTLM... So I try to extend the plugin in Xcode. But I really miss a lot of experience with Objective-C and can't manage to extend it myself.

The full code of the plugin can be found here: [CDVFileTransfer.m](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/src/ios/CDVFileTransfer.m)

I really think I have to edit something in the last code-block where I already succeeded to enter `if(self.trustAllHosts)`:

```
    // for self signed certificates
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge*)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        if (self.trustAllHosts) {
            NSURLCredential* credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
            [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

I've seen threads of collegues in which they try to implement NSURLCredentials as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825164/ntlm-authentication-from-ios-client)...

Anyone knows how to put those two pieces together, or isn't it that simple at all? If I could authorize with hardcoded credentials, I would be happy.